# Independence of errors assumption for simple linear regression

Tags: regression, linear

Concering the assumptions cited in all business statistics textbooks, they suggest that

a. the population errors should be independent and

b. follow the normal distribution with average 0,

c. have a constant std deviation, independent of the X values.

The tests for independence for cases when independence is absent, provide error plots, that obviously violate the rest of the assumptions.
For instance when clusters appear that attract errors above or below the trendline, obviously the zero mean assumption is also violated.
In addition, if clusters of concentrated small errors appear, the homoscedasticity assumption is violated.
So, why are these assumptions provided separately?
Are there cases, where only independence is violated?
Finally, could you provide a nice example of studying the relationship of two variables, and the population of errors is not independent and one where the population of errors is really independent? 
Intuitively, one could argue that for every quantitative characteristic, the error independence in the population could not be trully independent, because there must be some kind of error correlation because of another effect not considered in the model.
Could it be the case that we need independence on our sample data errors and not the population ones?
Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Time series data is correlated / dependent, and it may provide residuals which are normally distributed with mean 0. Depending on the data you may not even notice and patterns.